# Do a left join and sanitizing values at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

Consider the following two tables:

```
table1

id    key
---------
1     foo


table2

id    key1    key2
------------------
1     foo     444
2     (foo)   453
3     bar     355
```

I want to combine the information from both tables, as follows:

```
select    t1.id, t1.key, t2.key2
from      [table1] t1
left join [table2] t2 on t1.[key] = t2.[key1]
```

Which results in

```
id    key    key2
-----------------
1     foo    444
```

The issue is, I sometimes, values in `key1` have brackets `()`, but these I need to ignore. So in reality, also `(foo)` is actually `foo`, and the desired output therefore is:

```
id    key    key2
-----------------
1     foo    444
2     foo    453
```

Question: how should my query look like to get this done?

Comment: Aside: With SQL Server 2017 you could join `on t1.[key] = Trim( '()' from t2.[key] )`, but it isn't strictly correct. It may suffice for a one-shot cleanup but `'foo'` will match `'(foo)'`, `')foo('`, `'foo('`, `')foo)()()()'`, ... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a join condition to handle values that are surrounded by `()`. `in` comes to mind:

```
select    t1.id, t1.key, t2.key2
from      [table1] t1
left join [table2] t2 on t2.[key1] in (t1.[key], '(' + t1.[key] + ')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LTRIM`, `RTRIM`

```
   select    t1.id, t1.key, t2.key2
   from      [table1] t1
   left join [table2] t2 on
  RTRIM( LTRIM(t1.[key], '(') , ')' ) = 
    RTRIM( LTRIM(t2.[key], '(') , ')' )
```

Comment: A TRIM() function with 3 arguments. Where is it in the documentation?

Comment: Please dont just start showimg the answers to be incorrect always in some way or the other if the user doesnt have more rep. I saw trim working in oracle like that i have edited check now

Comment: You *saw trim working in oracle* and you assumed that SQL Server is the same as Oracle. Well it's not.

Comment: I never assumed that. It was that i saw the TRIM function supported in both the databases. Whatever though i have edited now.